Windows function to flag the first transaction and group subsequent transactions within a 7 day window in Spark SQL
I am trying to build a query in Spark SQL that will identify the transaction/record which starts a new 7 day window. The idea is to set a trigger for the first transaction and any transactions that happen within 7 days of that transaction will be grouped together, and the trigger will reset 8 days from the previous 7 day trigger.
Ideally, I'm hoping for results similar to this:



ID
Transaction Date
Amount
Trigger




1
16/09/2021
500
1


1
14/03/2022
200
1


1
18/03/2022
300
0


1
21/03/2022
100
0


1
22/03/2022
50
1


1
23/03/2022
60
0


1
29/03/2022
100
0


1
4/04/2022
100
1



One method that I've seen is to use recursive CTE's, but I believe Spark SQL does not support recursive CTE and I can only use Spark SQL at the moment so hoping to find an alternative method.
Another way I've been thinking is to group the transactions that occur within 7 days of the first transaction that triggers the 7 day flag, like so:



ID
Transaction Date
Amount
Group




1
16/09/2021
500
1


1
14/03/2022
200
2


1
18/03/2022
300
2


1
21/03/2022
100
2


1
22/03/2022
50
3


1
23/03/2022
60
3


1
29/03/2022
100
3


1
4/04/2022
100
4



But I haven't been able to figure out a way to get the sql logic for the groupings. Hoping to get some pointers or suggestions that can assist me.
Thank you in advance.
